# Drupal: upload multiple images for different nodes?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

is there a way in Drupal to upload all images first and create multiple nodes from it, and then fill all the nodes with the remaining text areas ?

In this way I don't have to upload the images one by one.

Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to ftp your images then add separate node details per image you could use something like: http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources to browse to the upload image on each node.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say "yes" is the answer, but it'll take some work.  I'm not familiar with any pre-built modules for this.  I'd probably start with SWFUpload (http://swfupload.org/) and the jQuery SWFUpload plugin (http://github.com/ifunk/swfupload-jquery-plugin).  Of course this will also require some back-end PHP work.

Comment: So, it is a tough tough process.

Comment: What about uploading all images in a "upload-type" node with SWFUpload and change with node api the submission of this node in order to create new nodes when this is saved, and assign them an image. But it is still too abstract.. I need more detailed explaination..